# deploy second app with the same image on shinyproxy server

Tags: shiny, shinyproxy

I have one shiny app running on shinyproxy server.  Here is what I put in the `application.yml`. It works fine.

```
name: user1
password: password
groups: app1

id: webapp1
display-name: application 1
description: web application 1
container-cmd: ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
container-image: mydockerimage
container-volumes: ["/data/data1:/srv/shiny-server/data"]
container-network: sp-example-net
port: 80
access-groups: [admins, app1]
```

Now I need to deploy the second app. This time I still use the same image. But mount on a different directory. `/data/data2` on host. I want it load a different sets of data and deployed to a different group of people.

Below is the code I *added* to the `application.yml`.

However, my shinyproxy server container failed to start.

Does anyone know why that happens?  How I can fix that?

```
name: user2
password: password
groups: app2

id: webapp2
display-name: application 2
description: web application 2
container-cmd: ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
container-image: mydockerimage
container-volumes: ["/data/data2:/srv/shiny-server/data"]
container-network: sp-example-net
port: 80
access-groups: [admins, app2]
```